How to fix faulty psd. file icons on Mac 27"
psd. files that have masked layers show up as an icon that only shows a layer mast when saved to a folder.The icon lacks the appearance of the full file.
27" iMac, OS Ventura 13.3.1 (a)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
